# ng-grid cell text wrapping and showing all cell text using eye button or link

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a simple ng-grid where the last column Lyrics can have short or long text inside it. I want to be able to detect when the text is really long and put a glyphicon button or a link that when clicked shows the entire text that cell. When the text is smaller that glyphicon button or link should disappear. Here are my grid contents:

```
$scope.students = [
    {name: "Annete T", age: 36,lyrics:'What is this love you talking about'}, 
    {name: "Ramona R", age: 42,lyrics:'Look at the stars how they shine for you in all their yellow'}, 
    {name: "Lisa J", age: 45,lyrics:'Where is my boat, what happened to my boat' },
    {name: "Hirit H", age:30,lyrics:'You had my heart inside of your soul and you played it to the beat beat'},
    {name: "Emily M", age: 40,lyrics:'Hello my love we meet again, its been a while since we been together'},
    {name: "Lynn M", age: 40,lyrics:'Hello '},
    {name: "Nicki M", age: 43,lyrics:'Can you take me higher , to a place with golden streets, can you take me higher'},
    {name: "Raveena M", age: 46,lyrics:'Where'}
];
```

And the plunker I created for the Grid http://plnkr.co/edit/uQBT70XSyRG7ijVSg5Vf

I saw the ng-grid CSS element code

```
.ngCellText {
     padding: 5px;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    white-space: nowrap;
   -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
   -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Is there a way to figure out when the cell is using this .ngCellText and then put a button

Comment: I guess the first thing I want to figure out is how to know when the cell text is long and when its short. I thought of length of the cell text, then I am thinking it might be in the ng-grid css. Can someone please help?

Comment: ng-grid adds a ellipsis at the end of each cell that is too long, so when there is an ellipsis I need to show a button that will show the entire trace

Answer (score 0):

You can figure how long is the text with `length`.
For example:

```
var message = 'cow';

//will be 3
message.length;
```

To make the message be showed in the lyrics column, just do a function above the `$scope.students` declaration, receiving the message and returning it short.

```
$scope.makeItShort = function(message){
   //put button with glyphicon and the message
   return 'short message';
};

$scope.shortMessage = function(message) {
  return (message.length > 20) ? $scope.makeItShort(message) : message;
};

$scope.students = [{
  name: "Annete T",
  age: 36,
  lyrics: $scope.shortMessage('What is this love you talking about')
}
```